# how to add a "/" slash sign to my measure result in dax

Tags: powerbi, format, dax, slash

I have 2 percentage measures in separate cards (e.g. 10% and 20%). I want to add a "/" slash sign between them (like this:  10% / 20%). How can I do this? I thought one way would be to add this sign to the end of the first formula, but it makes my percentage formula to a text. What would you advice me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Textbox in the middle with the "/" if it should not show in any other place otherwise you could create a measure that concatenates everything but that would be Text as an output but visually what you want

Comment: It doesn't work. One measure with IF formula & "/" & Second measure with IF formula :((

Comment: You should supply that information in the post or an example do it is clear what you are doing and what you expect as an outcome

Comment: yes, I want to add a "/" slash sign between 2 measures  (both are percentages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a final measure as below-

```
final_measure = CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(FORMAT([measure_1]*100.00,"##0.00"),"% / "),FORMAT([measure_2]*100,"##0.00")),"%")
```

here is a sample output-

[image]

Comment: Thank you soooo much ^_^ It worked well.  Thanks again. You helped me very much !

Comment: @NatiaMikava can you please mark the answer as eccept? Also you can put an up vote :)